# How can I echo a shell command as a string

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I want place the following string into my .zshrc file using the command line

`eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"`

I've tried:

`echo "eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"" >> .zshrc`

and every other `` ` `` and `'` combination

The result I want is to have my .zshrc file execute
`eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"`
much like it does for homebrew
`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

I just want to be able to write to my .zshrc file using echo. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is `> .zshrc`  missing ?

Comment: @Ôrel Yes sorry. Added. That is the command I've been trying. one > wipes out the whole file. Need to append to it.

Comment: You've tried "every combination"?  What was wrong with `echo 'eval "$(docker exec -it abc 123)"' >> $HOME/.zshrc`?

Comment: Why so complicated? Just do a `nano ~/.zshrc` (or whatever you prefer here) and paste your command at the place you want to have it.

Comment: @user1934428 It's for documentation. Don't want the user to do too much. One quick command was required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"' >> .zshrc
```

Will add

```
eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"
```

at the end of your `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 1):

A here doc can print a string verbatim, without quoting issues:

```
cat <<"EOF" >> .zshrc
eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"
EOF
```

In this case, you could do `echo 'eval "$(docker exec -it <abc-123>)"' >> .zshrc`, provided `<abc-123>` doesn't contain a single quote (`'`).